# How replace one list items with another in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have two array lists, Can it possible to replace the one list items with the second list.

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("testone");
a.add("testtwo");
a.add("testthree");
b.add("demoone");
b.add("demotwo");
System.out.println("List values are: "+ a);
```

Is there any way to replace the first list with the second list elements. So if I print first array list, it should print the following output

```
[demoone, demotwo]
```

Comment: you need to clarify, if it is possible to you to manipulate the references, or not

Comment: Do you want to change whole list, or you want to replace individual value in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need:

```
a = b;
System.out.println("List values are: "+ a);
```

Comment: than he removes elements from his "second" list and first list is changed. OP needed some java basics instead of quick solutions.

Answer (score 3):

simplest way to do is assign list b to list a

```
a=b
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1:

```
a = b; //copy same list reference
```

Option 2:

```
a.clear(); //clear all existing items
a.addAll(b); //copy all
```

Option 3:

```
a = (ArrayList<String>)b.clone(); //shallow copy
```

Answer (score 2):

So there are two ways to do this based on requirement.

1. You need the list referenced by reference variable `b` to be available with the reference variable `a`. In this case the original list referenced by `a` is not required to be modified, just the reference variable `a` is being pointed to the second list (originally referenced by reference variable `b`).

   ```
   a = b;
   System.out.println("List values are: "+ a);
   ```
2. You need the list referenced by reference variable `a` to have the items present in the list referenced by `b`. In this case, the actual list originally referenced by `a` has to be modified. This might be required when you are passing the list to a method which is supposed to modify the list.

   ```
   a.clear();
   a.addAll(b);
   System.out.println("List values are: "+ a);
   ```